# MS Access keeps prompting for Login

Tags: ms-access

For some reason when i try and create a new MS Access database(.mdb), i get prompted for a login/password even if the database isn't protected.  Any ideas as to how to get rid of this?
Note i'm using MS Access 2007.  I tried to add a password to database by going into "Database Tools", "User and Group Accounts", "Change Logon Password".

Comment: Is the Access database connected/linked to other (for instance SQL) databases?

Comment: not it's not linked to any other database, i'm trying to create a from a blank database. I tried to add a password  to database and from then on, it's started prompting me to enter a password. I've edited my response to show what i did.

Answer (score 2):

Did someone make changes to system.mdw? What, if anything, is returned if you paste this:

```
?CurrentProject.Connection.Properties("Jet OLEDB:System database")
```

Into the immediate window?

Response to recent edit:

Using the above line, you can find the system.mdw. If you delete it, it will be recreated, but be careful, because you could lose your ability to access some mdbs, depending on exactly what you did.

Comment: i can't get past database logon prompt to get to immediate window. Note edits i have made to original request above

Comment: Do you not know what the new password is?

Comment: i enter the password i registered, but it's not recognising it.

Comment: What about the old password? Did you have one?

Comment: there was no password on the database previously.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for helping guys. I realise the mistake that i made. When i created password, it must have joined me to a workgroup. Hence when i was prompted for a password, my network ID was displayed, so when i entered new password,  i was denied access. When i tried logging in using Admin and password , that allowed me to login.

Comment: You're always joined to a workgroup with Jet -- the default logon is "admin" with no password. You don't see a logon prompt until you put a password on the admin account. This is Jet ULS 101. Anyone using Jet should know all of this, and if you don't, you really need to spend some time learning about the basics of the db engine you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find this file: System.mdw and delete it (you have previously used user level security and Access aply it to every single archive)

Hope it helps

Comment: Excuse me, i think i have the same issue.. How do you find the file refferred to above?

Comment: Hi, in my pc is in the following direction: C:\Users\\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access just be careful, archive AppData is hidden!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and for the purposes of clarity I'm posting the solution here (DWFenton posted the solution in a comment above originally).

If Access keeps prompting you to enter a login and password when you do not wish to use User Groups you need to remove the password for the default admin account.

User and Group Accounts > Change logon password. For the admin account leave the new password fields blank and the logon/password request dialog will not appear when you next login.

Answer (score 0):

Before change

[image: Before change]

After pasting in the connection info

[image: After pasting in connection info]

I wanted to add that it is possible that your queries have not stored your ODBC's connection string info.  I had to go into mine and paste in the details for every query and save the query. Worked like a charm.  The first image shows the 'perpetual login' situation when I would get prompted for login details over and over.  The "ODBC Connect Str" simple said "ODBC;".  The second shows (part) of the full connection string (including username and password [naughty, I know] information for the SQL server) that I pasted in.  Works like a charm.  I am sure there is a better and more proper way to do this and I would love to go back and clean it up if anyone has a suggestion.